# Prevent duplication in between same id's item but it's ok to duplicate between different id

Tags: php, laravel

This is a bit hard to solve for me. I want to prevent duplication between same id's item in DB. But it's ok to duplicate between different id.

For example when the scraping bot run. It scrapes a website. Taking "plan names" from different pages. Some times different pages has same plan name. it means duplication is ok for the different id. But not the same page's item(I mean same id)

The code block below. It prevent all duplication. I am not sure how to improve it.

```
foreach($planNames as $k => $names)
{
    $database = [];
    $database = [
        "place_id" => $insertedPlaceId,
        "plan_name" => $names,
        "plan_price" => $planPrice[$k],
        "people" => $people[$k]
    ];


    if ($place = Plan::where("plan_name", "=", $names)->first()) {

    } else {
        Plan::insertGetId($database);
        $this->line("Plans inserted.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a bit hard to understand also. Can you give an example if what you want to happen or what you want to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to prevent same `plan_name` in same `place_id` therefore you should query this

```
$place = Plan::where("plan_name", "=", $names)->where("place_id", $insertedPlaceId)->first();
```

then check if its empty or not.

Hope it helps. If my understanding on your question is wrong then kindly correct me. Thanks

Comment: it's working but not correctly. sorry for the lack of explanation. I am scraping plan names and etc. from a website. in that website every plan has it's own page. So `place_id` means plan page. And not always but sometimes different page has same plan name. That time I ok to duplicate plan name for different `place_id`. But not ok for the same `place_id`. By the way I run the code, but it start to give different plan name to different page. I mean this time plan names not coming to correct page... But yea it's very much duplicate the plan names... :) home I make it more clear now.

Comment: Just to confirm its okay to have same `plan_name` in different `place_id` but not with the same `place_id` right? what is the result of my answer?

Comment: yes that's right. it' okay to have same `plan_name` in different id, but not with the same `place_id`. I run your answer, but this time not giving the correct `plan_name` to correct `place_id`.

Comment: Wait what? My answer is just select not insert. Then maybe the problem lies on your insert. You should check if you're getting the right `$insertedPlaceId` you want or the full data just try to use `dd();` to check the data

Comment: My answer is just checking the plan in the `$insertedPlaceId(place_id)` if has already that `plan_name`

Comment: in the insert part there is no problem because, the code block in the question inserts the data correctly? but when I write second `where()` of yours, insert part is starting to corrupt.

Comment: the one that you're inserting is on `$database` right? then it should not have effect on the query that I answered because its just a select query not a insert or changing a data. Maybe you should input your full controller in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198566/discussion-between-jovs-and-mr-hello).